# What is 'xorl' and 'imul' are used for in this assembly code? Can it be converted to c Code?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, att

```
int func2(int x, int y)
    
movl 4(%esp), %eax          
addl 8(%esp), %eax            
xorl $255,%eax            
imul 8(%esp), %eax            
sall $4, eax
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Edit your question and put the code back in as text (properly formatted).

Comment: Not sure I understand the questions about what those operations are "used for". `xorl` performs an exclusive OR and `imul` performs an integer multiplication. If you're really wondering what the ultimate purpose of those operations is, that's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

The C code corresponding to this function is something like

```
int func2(int x, int y)
{
    int eax;

    eax = x;
    eax += y;
    eax ^= 0xff;
    eax *= y;
    eax <<= 4;

    return (eax);
}
```

What that is supposed to do... I have no idea.